# Web scraping behance.net

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to parse https://www.behance.net/gallery/35092257/LEmpreinte-du-Geste using Nokogiri.

The parsed page does not include all the META tags in the `<head>` that I can see by viewing the page source on that page. Any idea why this is so?

This is the code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'https://www.behance.net/gallery/35092257/LEmpreinte-du-Geste'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[mcve]". We need to see the minimal input HTML necessary to demonstrate the problem, along with your expected output. Don't ask us to scan through a full page to find what you're looking for; It wastes our time doing what you're supposed to have done. Using a source view in a browser isn't accurate. Use `wget` or `curl` or OpenURI in IRB, or simply use `nokogiri some_url` at the command-line to see what is really there.

Answer (score 1):

This page is built on top of [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/), that builds a [shadow dom](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) on the fly.

Nokogiri is HTML/XML parser, it is by no means a JavaScript parser. Why do you expect it to execute JavaScript?

`wget` the page and you’ll see that in fact it contains not one line of HTML, besides tags like `<html>` and `<head>`.

You might try to pass the downloaded page to [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/), but I doubt it will be able to execute either.